# Отсутствует wlan0 в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wlan

`iwconfig` показывает только `enp4s0` и `lo`.
Как мне настроить интернет?

upd. я просто поставила драйвер и пару пакетов, правильные версии которых прятались в недрах загрузочной флехи (а я то рыскала в их поиске, что только не делала). для такого профана как я это было неочевидно. может кому поможет в дальнейшем.

Comment: lspci что показывает?

Comment: Драйвер на карточку поставить надо

Comment: "ifconfig -a" что показывает?

Comment: Стоп. А что с предыдущим вопросом? Который http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542650/191416

Comment: какой-то из двух вопросов — дубль: [1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542650/178576) или [2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542865/178576).

Comment: @Elizaveta, вопрос в лоб: а у вас в компьютере вообще есть *wifi-адаптер*?

Comment: ifconfig тоже показывает эти два девайса, lspci находит "Network controller: Broadwork Corporation .....блабла", что делать дальше не пойму. Я малоопытна в линуксах, было бы здорово, если кините ссыль и как-то посоветуете, что делать.

Answer (score 1):

`enp4s0` - это и есть старый, добрый `eth0`, его и настраиваем. Но..
Можно и так:
Идем в `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` и меняем:

```
KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="enp4s0"
```

на

```
KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="wlan0"
```

или `"eth0"`.